# Sharepoint 2010 does not allow anonymous users to see pictures from an image library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So I have a public facing Sharepoint 2010 site. I have enabled anonymous users on the farm as well as on the site.

The site itself displays perfect if you log in, but as an anonymous user it will not display any of the pictures from an image library. (All the text come through fine).

If I attempt to access the image library directly, (a url pointing to an image inside the library) I get a 401 error.

I have attempted to adjust the permissions on the library itself, but I still cannot get the pictures to display.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If site and rest of the list/libraries are accessible to anonymous users, it is very likely that the security of the images library has been overridden. Make sure the images library is inheriting the permissions of parent site which has anonymous access enabled.

Also, turn off versioning in the images library if it is turned on.

Comment: Thanks. They all had to be published and I turned off versioning,  now it works

Comment: Amazing, turning the versioning off worked, it still works if I turn it on again!